# Rx Task ToObservable() not found

Tags: c#, .net, task, system.reactive

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with .NET framework version 4.5.1

I am reading tutorials on Reactive Extensions, and am trying to run this code:

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => "Test");
var source = t.ToObservable();
```

`t.ToObservable()` is underlined and gives me the error

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<.string> does not contain definition for ToObservable...

I read in another post that I should download Silverlight Toolkit and include the `System.Reactive.dll` it comes with as a reference, but that did not help.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you `using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;`?

Comment: Hey that actually fixed it! I didn't think it would be because I am missing a using statement, because I always rely on right-clicking on the error -> Resolve -> using missingReference. Thanks!

Comment: @user1136506 You can use "SLaks" answer as answer, so it will help others

Comment: But how come right-clicking on the error -> Resolve didn't add the reference for me this time? I always rely on that to find my missing references...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That extension method is defined in the `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` namespace.

You need to import the namespace first.